# Can you have tabbed windows in access?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

First time ms access user. Just wondering why there are no tabs in access when you open things (tables, queries, forms, etc.) Is there a plugin I can download that fixes this?

[Access No Tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1TCx.jpg)

Comment: File, Options, Current Database, Document Window Options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select *Tabbed Documents* in Access options.

[image]

You must close and re-open the database to apply that change.